# How to solve $(\partial_xu)^2\partial_{xx}u+2\partial_xu\partial_yu\partial_{xy}u+(\partial_yu)^2\partial_{yy}u=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> How to solve $(\partial_xu)^2\partial_{xx}u+2\partial_xu\partial_yu\partial_{xy}u+(\partial_yu)^2\partial_{yy}u=0$ in $\mathbb R^2$

If I write $(\partial_x+\partial_y)^2u=\partial_{xx}u+2\partial_{xy}u+\partial_{yy}u$ I get the above without ''coefficients''.

and $(\partial_xu+\partial_yu)^2$ gives the coefficients.

How can I combine both ?

There is written that I shall use separation of variables but a different ''Ansatz'' then $f(x)g(y)$

**EDIT**: Well I got another hint that $u_{xy}=0$, then I can solve it, but at least can one explain why $u_{xy}=0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

What are domain and range for $u$?

It is probably not so in your question, but if we assume $u:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ to be holomorphic (where here we identify the domain with $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $z = x+iy$) then we have the Cauchy-Riemann equations telling us that $\partial_yu = i\partial_xu$, so that the left hand side of equation becomes
$$(\partial_xu)^2\partial_{xx}u + 2 (\partial_xu)(i\partial_xu)(i\partial_{xx}u) + (i\partial_xu)^2(-\partial_{xx}u)$$
which is always zero.